# Want to add a element in desired index. But adding last

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I use add method to add an element to a desired index. But it is adding last. I want to add an element to a desired index. How can do it with this. Is is possible? without end pointer.

```
import java.util.*;

class List {

    Customer listPtr;
    int index;

    public void add(Customer customer) {
        Customer temp = customer;
        if (listPtr == null) {
            listPtr = temp;
            index++;
         } else {
        Customer x = listPtr;
            while (x.next != null) {
                x = x.next;
            }
            x.next = temp;
            index++;
        }
    }

    public void add(int index, Customer customer) {
        int size = size();
        while (size != -1) {
            size--;
            if (size == index) {
                System.out.println(size + ":" + index);
                add(customer);
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeFirst() {
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        if (listPtr != null) {
            listPtr = temp.next;
        }
    }

    public void removeLast() {
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp.next.next != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = null;
        index--;
    }

    public void removeAll() {
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp != null) {
            listPtr = temp.next;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp != null) {
            size++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public void printList() {
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}

class DemoList {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List list = new List();
        Customer c1 = new Customer("10011", "Sam");
        Customer c2 = new Customer("10012", "Jason");
        Customer c3 = new Customer("10013", "Arnold");
        Customer c4 = new Customer("10014", "Bob");
        Customer c5 = new Customer("10015", "Tom");
        list.add(c1);
        list.add(c2);
        list.add(c3);
        list.add(c4);
        list.add(2, c5);
        System.out.println(list.size());
        list.printList();
    }
}

class Customer {

    String id;
    String name;
    Customer next;

    public Customer(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id + " : " + name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object ob) {
        Customer c = (Customer) ob;
        return this.id.equals(c.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `add(int index, Customer customer)` method simply calls your `add(Customer customer)` method, so it will clearly add it to the end.

Comment: If I want to add an element in after 10012 and before 10013, how can I do it?

Comment: In the `add(int index, Customer customer)` method, instead of calling `add(Customer customer)` manually readjust your pointers at the specified index.

Comment: Try to figure out how you would splice a `Customer` after another in your list.  Don't write code; just draw things out on a blackboard or paper.  Then, implement it.  Also, try to write a set of unit tests for what you want to do. Then, make the tests succeed.

Comment: I tried to do it. But I have no idea about how to store available elements. If I updated pointer, that all elements are removed.

Comment: Another way is to think recursively.  Adding at position `i` has 2 cases: `i==0`.  Here you want push the new item onto the rest of the list and make the list head the new item.  The other case is `i>0`.  Here you want to insert at the `i-1`th position of the list's tail (i.e. the list with the head element omitted).  This is e easily done with a recursive call.  Implementing these two cases will produce a tail recursive function, which will compile to quite efficient code.

Comment: I'm still in my problem. I think it is not possible with me.. :(

Comment: I tried with this. But it hasn't last elements.
public void add(int index,Customer customer){
  int size = size();
  Customer temp = listPtr;  
  while(temp!=null){
   size--;      
   if(size==index){
    System.out.println(size+" : "+index);    
    listPtr.next = customer;    
    temp = temp.next;
   } 
   //temp = temp.next;  
  }
 }

Comment: Can anyone give me a code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, finds index from the beginning and adds `customer` at that position

```
public void add(int index, Customer customer) {
    int size = size();
    Customer tmp=listPtr,tmp2;
    int i=0;
     //some boundary cases
    if((index<0) ||(index>size)){
       return;
    }
    //assumes all other cases are handled
    while (i != size) {            
        if ((i+1) == index) {
            System.out.println(size + ":" + index);
            tmp2=tmp.next;
            tmp.next=customer;
            customer.next=tmp2;
            break;
        }
        tmp=tmp.next;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I implement this for remove by index?

Comment: I can't add an element to the 0th index by using this.

Comment: it assumes index is from 1 to n..not starting from 0

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two `Customer`s, `a`, and `b`, and they are hooked up together.

```
Customer a = new Customer("a", "John");
Customer b = new Customer("b", "George");
a.next = b;
```

Now, you want to slip `c` between them:

```
Customer c = new Customer("c", "Paul");
```

You want eventually to have `a.next == c` and `c.next == b`.  But if you make those changes in the wrong order, your list will have `b` detached from the rest of the list, and it will be garbage collected.  So, do things in the correct order so nothing is lost:

```
c.next = b;  // Now, both a.next and c.next == b.
a.next = c;  // Finishing the splice.  Now, a.next == c and c.next == b.
```

To insert items into the list, advance from the beginning`index` places.

```
Customer nth(int n) {
    Customer cust = listPtr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cust = cust.next;  // can lead to an NPE; you add the error checking.
    }
    return cust;
}
```

Now, get the `nth` customer, and splice a new one in.  Again, watch out for NPEs.

Comment: I didn't get you. How can I do all the things in nth method?

Comment: No, just use `nth` to find the n-th element in your list.  Then, use the result and splice the new member in.  Stop thinking that you have to do *everything* in just one member function. Break up your problem into small pieces, figure out how to do each piece, and put them together.